# How can I iterate over unordered JSON data and sort into an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm grabbing data from an API which is in a json object structure. The problem is that this json is not in order and I understand is unordered by nature. I was wondering how I could iterate over these keys and sort this data by putting them in an array (I already have them printing out in a table using ng-repeat but they are in random order so my end goal is to have them displayed in order by date). Here is an example of the structure:

```
{
    "01/05/2016": {
         "Something1": {},
         "Something2": {}      
     },
    "01/01/2016": {
         "Something1": {},
         "Something2": {}      
     },
    "01/03/2016": {
         "Something1": {},
         "Something2": {}      
     }
}

 <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in metrics_data">
          <td align="center">{{key}}</td>
          //and then I do another ng-repeat right here for values
```

Comment: Are all your dates guaranteed to be from the same year? If so you can take advantage of `Array.prototype.sort`.

Comment: why not use orderBy filter?

Comment: I tried but that only works for arrays. My structure is in json. The dates are not guaranteed to be from same year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the fact that orderBy doesn't support object. so just convert the object into array first.

```
$scope.testObj = {
"01/05/2016": {
     "Something1": {},
     "Something2": {}      
 },
"01/01/2016": {
     "Something1": {},
     "Something2": {}      
 },
"01/03/2016": {
     "Something1": {},
     "Something2": {}      
 }
};

$scope.testObjArray = Object.keys($scope.testObj).map(
                     function(k) { 
                         return {key: k, value: $scope.testObj[k]} 
                     });
```

then use orderBy

```
ng-repeat="obj in testObjArray | orderBy : 'key'"
```

see http://plnkr.co/edit/AhRWwhp0a5gndC7RByqt?p=preview

Comment: The order will not work if your dates are 01/05/2016, 01/01/2015, 01/03/2016

Comment: What happens if one of the value is 01/03/2015?

Comment: Will sorted as 01/01/2016

01/03/2015

01/05/2016

Comment: Thank you, just finished it up and it looks like it is working. I have not tested it on different years..so will have to look into that. Any possible solutions to handle that case?

Comment: since the date is a just a string, you need to convert it into a proper Date object in order to sort it properly. just do it inside of the mapper. i.e. return {key : new Date(k), value : $scope.testObj[k]};. Anyway, you can convert the key to whatever you like and sort it.

Comment: you're an angular wizard! Thank you for the help @sdfacre!

Comment: @sdfacre And you can use the date filter with the expression:  {{ obj.key | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}